# Detection, number of elements per line according to resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this example:

[link](https://codepen.io/cristian-marius/pen/WNeVZvX)

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var win = $(this); //this = window

  if (win.width() >= 1280) {
    var prodPerLine = "3"
  }

  if (win.width() >= 768) {
    var prodPerLine = "2"
  }

  if (win.width() >= 420) {
    var prodPerLine = "1"
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  ul li {
    width: 49%;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to save in a javascript variable, how many elements are in a row depending on the resolution.

How can I do this?
Is a switch case type decision structure needed?

I tried to make an example but it is not completed because I do not realize what algorithm we should have in the back to detect the number of products in a row, depending on the resolution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/ropy1xsL/ . open the console log and try and resize the window.

Comment: yes, is perfect

Comment: Or even.... https://codepen.io/PeterA/pen/mdbNBXm

Comment: you might also use a min-width and a single mediaquerie to set your break points https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WNeVXbL without javascript mediaquerie